# CPU-Bound or I/O-Bound

Tags: linux, process

How to make the Linux system as CPU-bounded rather than I/O-bounded.

I want to run the mplayer with most-highest priority than any other processes, including copying data from/to one-storage device or from/to over network to/from the local storage device.

Normally, when I started the copying action, the video stuck for a moment, and continued to play again. This process repeats itself, till the copying operation get completed.

If copying takes more time, then I do not mind.

Any idea, how can I do that ?

Regards,
Satish

Answer (score 3):

`ionice` lets you specify the IO priority of a process on recent Linux kernels

e.g.

```
ionice -c 1 -n 0 mplayer ...
```

Comment: I tried this command, but it did not ring the bell. Any other way to do ?

Comment: you can retrospectively apply io scheduler priorities to a process using ionice by passing and existing PID using the -p option

Comment: I tried that too, but it was of no use, as the mplayer get stucks when the I/O operation starts.

Comment: You can always run the other io processes at low priority too.